# Consume no message from spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 with option kafka.bootstrap.servers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka `1.0.1-kafka-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT` from CDH (cloudera distribution for hadoop)

On my batch-1 edge server, **I can produce** messages with :

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list batch-1:9092 --topic MyTopic
```

**I can consume** messages thanks to Zookeeper on my first node with :

```
kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper data1:2181 --topic MyTopic --from-beginning
```

But I get **nothing** with **bootstrap-server option** :

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server batch-1:9092 --topic MyTopic --from-beginning
```

The problem is i'm using kafka on spark :

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0"`

```
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "batch-1:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "MyTopic")
  .load()

println("Select :")

val df2 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(topic AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String, String)]

println("Show :")

val query = df2.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I did an `export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10` on my edge. Then

```
spark2-submit --driver-memory 2G --jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera4.jar --class "spark.streaming.Poc" poc_spark_kafka_2.11-0.0.1.jar
```

**This force me to use** `kafka.bootstrap.servers`, it seems to be connected, but I can't get any message.

The output is the same as the `kafka-console-consumer` with `--bootstrap-server` option :

```
18/10/30 16:11:48 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0-kafka-2.1.0
18/10/30 16:11:48 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : unknown
18/10/30 16:11:48 INFO streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
```

Then, nothing. 
Should I connect to Zookeeper ? How ?

Is there a version conflict whereas they said "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version **0.10.0 or higher**)" here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html ?

What did I missed ?

Comment: Did you check, if your broker is actually running? When I do a local setup with a very similar spark streaming program, everything works. The fact, that your console consumers are not showing anything, leads me to think, that there is a problem with the producer.

Comment: As of Kafka 0.9 and up, consumers and producers should not be using Zookeeper. The console consumer with the boostrap server should work before you can expect Spark to work. Also, Spark might start at the latest offset of your topic unless otherwise configured

Comment: @Elmar Macek, I guess the producer is fine because I consume messages from the console consumer using zookeeper.

Comment: @cricket_007 That's exactly the problem and why i'm disapointed : it should not use zookeeper in 1.0.
Thank you both for your fast answers.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

The `/var/log/kafka/kafka-broker-batch-1.log` said :

`2018-10-31 13:40:08,284 ERROR kafka.server.KafkaApis: [KafkaApi-51] Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet.`

So I deployed **3 brokers** on my cluster nodes with a gateway on the edge, now it works with :

`kafka-console-producer --broker-list data1:9092,data2:9092,data3:9092 --topic Test`

`kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server data1:9092 --topic Test --from-beginning`

Spark works fine too.

Comment: So, yeah, consuming with Zookeeper would have stored the offsets there, rather than the offsets topic